# lxml.etree.XML ValueError for Unicode string

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-3.4

I'm transforming [an xml](https://gist.github.com/guinslym/5ce47460a31fe4c4046b#file-original_xml-xml) document with [xslt](https://gist.github.com/guinslym/5ce47460a31fe4c4046b#file-test_xslt-xslt). While doing it with python3 I had this following error. But I don't have any errors with python2

```
-> % python3 cstm/artefact.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cstm/artefact.py", line 98, in <module>
    simplify_this_dataset('fisheries-service-des-peches.xml')
  File "cstm/artefact.py", line 85, in simplify_this_dataset
    xslt_root = etree.XML(xslt_content)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3012, in lxml.etree.XML (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:67861)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1780, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102420)
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.

#!/usr/bin/env python3
# vim:fileencoding=UTF-8:ts=4:sw=4:sta:et:sts=4:ai
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from lxml import etree

def simplify_this_dataset(dataset):
    """Create A simplify version of an xml file
    it will remove all the attributes and assign them as Elements instead
    """
    module_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    data = open(module_path+'/data/ex-fire.xslt')
    xslt_content = data.read()
    xslt_root = etree.XML(xslt_content)
    dom = etree.parse(module_path+'/../CanSTM_dataset/'+dataset)
    transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
    result = transform(dom)
    f = open(module_path+ '/../CanSTM_dataset/otra.xml', 'w')
    f.write(str(result))
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
data = open(module_path+'/data/ex-fire.xslt')
xslt_content = data.read()
```

This implicitly decodes the bytes in the file to Unicode text, using the default encoding. (This might give wrong results, if the XML file isn't in that encoding.)

```
xslt_root = etree.XML(xslt_content)
```

XML has its own handling and signalling for encodings, the `<?xml encoding="..."?>` prolog. If you pass a Unicode string starting with `<?xml encoding="..."?>` to a parser, the parser would like to reintrepret the rest of the byte string using that encoding... but can't, because you've already decoded the byte input to a Unicode string.

Instead, you should either pass the undecoded byte string to the parser:

```
data = open(module_path+'/data/ex-fire.xslt', 'rb')

xslt_content = data.read()
xslt_root = etree.XML(xslt_content)
```

or, better, just have the parser read straight from the file:

```
xslt_root = etree.parse(module_path+'/data/ex-fire.xslt')
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also decode the UTF-8 string and encode it with ascii before passing it to etree.XML

```
 xslt_content = data.read()
 xslt_content = xslt_content.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii')
 xslt_root = etree.XML(xslt_content)
```

Comment: Why would you encode it as ascii when the initial declaration suggests utf-8 possibility?

Comment: I made it work by simply reencoding with the default options:  

    xslt_content = data.read().encode()

Answer (score 10):

I made it work by simply reencoding with the default options

```
xslt_content = data.read().encode()
```