# python parse XML with lxml giving the right parser parameters

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xpath, lxml

I am parsing xml data with lxml in python

The data looks like this:

```
string='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/n
    <div type="request" xml:base="/k-api/7728" xml:lang="en" >
    <div n="" type="request" xml:id="_54f59d0003">
        <p xml:id="_54f59d0004"/>
        <p xml:id="_54f59d0005">Requests </p>
    </div>
    <div n="0001" type="request" xml:id="_54f59d0006">
        <p xml:id="_54f59d0007">1.  First request.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div n="0002" type="claim" xml:id="_54f59d0008">
         <p xml:id="_54f59d0009">2. Second request.
         </p>
    </div>
    <div n="0003" type="request" xml:id="_54f59d0010">
         <p xml:id="_54f59d0011">3. Thrid requests.
         </p>
    </div>
    <div n="0004" type="request" xml:id="_54f59d0012">
        <p xml:id="_54f59d0013">4. request.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>'''


import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding="UTF-8", resolve_entities=False, strip_cdata=False, recover=True, ns_clean=True)
XML_tree = etree.fromstring(xml_string,parser=parser)
```

This does not work because several reasons
a) the line break \n: I can solve that by

```
xml_string = ''.join(string.splitlines())
```

but I am wondering if there is a way to tell in the parser that lxml should not take care of line breaks
b) Utf-8 first line in the string. I can also take care of it by:

```
xml_string = xml_string.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>','')
```

before parsing, but is there a way to do it all inside the lxml parser?, i.e telling the parser to remove line breaks and to forget about the encoding (note: encoding="UTF-8" or encoding=None will not solve the problem)

Thanks

EDIT 1: The rror that I get when not removing the encoding bit is:
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, using triple quotes around `string` and `XML_tree = etree.fromstring(string.encode('utf-8'), parser=parser)`

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534460/lxml-etree-xml-valueerror-for-unicode-string re the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

etree.fromstring() function should have the XML string input encoded as bytes to parse correctly if the XML fragment includes the XML declaration.

Alternatively, can use `ElementTree.fromstring()` function.

```xml
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree

xml_string = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div...>
</div>'''

parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding="UTF-8", resolve_entities=False, strip_cdata=False, recover=True, ns_clean=True)

# Option 1
root = etree.fromstring(xml_string.encode('utf-8'), parser)

# Option 2
root = ET.fromstring(xml_string, parser)

# do something with the parsed XML

pretty_xml = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, encoding=str)
print(pretty_xml)
```